# Loading hive-partitioned ORC data into bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have hive data  partitioned  by **ts_date** and **orid** and below is the sample cloud storage url for the files

```
myhivepartionedbucket/crunched-logs/mrs-suds-sloaders/loader-log/output/{year}/{month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Min}/ts_date={yyyy-mm-dd}/orid={orid}/file.orc
```

Below is the cloud storage actual url in production

```
myhivepartionedbucket/crunched-logs/mrs-suds-sloaders/loader-log/output/2020/08/06/00/30/ts_date=2020-08-05/orid=6691/part-202008060030.orc
```

This kind of structure will be there for all the days for each month with 24hrs separated by each hour for all the orid's

Now we want to schedule to load this kind of data to big query with partition by ts_date and clustering by orid.

I have tried on the console for one file without partition, I'm able to load the data, but how can I schedule and load this kind of data regularly with partition by **ts_date** and cluster by **orid**.

I'm new to GCP and not enough understanding from docs provided by google so can somebody guide or give me ideas to run  on UI or program in python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer-overview#wildcard-support) with a common prefix, like:

```
myhivepartionedbucket/crunched-logs/mrs-suds-sloaders/loader-log/output/*.orc
```

To load all your files containing your ORC data.

Make sure to enable Source Data Partitioning when you [load ORC data through the console](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-orc#loading_orc_data_into_a_new_table).

The console allows you to set several parameters including partitioning and clustering. However, in order to [partition by column(s)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#console), is required that the schema inferred from the ORC file has at least one column of DATE or TIMESTAMP type, otherwise, this option is not available when loading your ORC data. Since you're planning to partition using a column detected through your URI path (ts_date) this option may not be available, so my suggestion would be to load it as a regular table and then [creating the partitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_a_partitioned_table_from_a_query_result)/[clustered](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#creating_clustered_tables) table from query results of the regular table.

Finally, once you have your partitioned/clustered table, you can use it as destination of [BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer), which allows you to schedule recurring data loads from Cloud Storage to BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answr, replacing timestamp wont help me as i have that hive partioned data is in s3 and im loading into cloud storage via transfer and ts_date is available in column

Comment: I've edited my answer, replicated a similar scenario and there's no need to change the path. Using a wildcard with a common prefix will be enough to match all your ORC files and detect your ts_date and orid parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have the same problem as the original question. I have partitioned files that I want to load in partitioned table. I can indeed first create a normal table with the schema of my file + the schema contained in the filepath name. Which I can then transform in a new partitioned table. But I'm unable to add data to this partitioned table. 
While using `bq mk --transfer_config` it complains I'm missing columns in my file (so it does not pickup the URI columns).
Or with `bq load` it complains that the URI columns already exist.